# using downward arrow in an equation

Tags: equations

How can I use a downward arrow in a formulae as the below example:

[image]

There are some examples in other formats same as using `$\underbrace{x}_{y}$` in equations but I could not find a desired style of an equation.

Comment: There's [pdftex - Arrow Between Equations - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400590/arrow-between-equations) ...

Comment: Or [Arrows pointing to equation - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276032/arrows-pointing-to-equation) . the first one looks like the same, but that one probably wouldn't be able to make the arrow perfectly vertical (or maybe it can if it's possible to anchor, or some coordinate computation or something)

Comment: Thanks a bunch. yes ...if it drawn vertical it should be better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done in a variety of ways as in the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/400590/125871), or you could use an `align` environment, using the `B` character. The `\downarrow` needs a small shift to the left as shown:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
A={}&B+C\\
&\hspace{-.2ex}\downarrow\\
&B=R+q
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

If you want to adjust the spacing around the arrow, you can add negative space after the appropriate lines:

```
\begin{align*}
A={}&B+C\\[-1ex]
&\hspace{-.2ex}\downarrow\\[-.5ex]
&B=R+q
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to reduce the gap between arrow and the equations?

Comment: You could add `[-1ex]` (or any length) after the double backslash in the first and second lines of the `align*` environment. You can have different lengths for each line if you want.

Comment: @SandyG +1 I am agree with you with the second comment.

Comment: @SandyG: [Another option](https://pastebin.com/raw/7k64hVdM), using something similar to `\vdotswithin` from [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools).